# A record in Route 53 doesn't resolve

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns-zone, amazon-route53, amazon-cloudfront

I added an A record in my Route 53 hosted zone pointing to the CloudFront. But for some reason, it doesn't work.

[image: route 53 hosted zone screenshot]

[image: route 53 A record edit popup]

When I do `dig mywebsite.com`

I get

```
; <<>> DiG 9.16.1-Ubuntu <<>> mywebsite.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 42985
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;mywebsite.com.         IN  A

;; Query time: 71 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53)
;; WHEN: Пт окт 01 20:29:47 MSK 2021
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 41
```

I just don't understand why my A record is empty here.

I added ns records to my domain registrator's panel.

```
; <<>> DiG 9.16.1-Ubuntu <<>> ns mywebsite.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 2245
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 4, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;mywebsite.com.         IN  NS

;; ANSWER SECTION:
mywebsite.com.      2435    IN  NS  ns-1899.awsdns-45.co.uk.
mywebsite.com.      2435    IN  NS  ns-881.awsdns-46.net.
mywebsite.com.      2435    IN  NS  ns-494.awsdns-61.com.
mywebsite.com.      2435    IN  NS  ns-1077.awsdns-06.org.

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53)
;; WHEN: Пт окт 01 20:34:00 MSK 2021
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 181
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show a screenshot of Route53. You'll get better, faster help if you share your actual domain name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you host static website on S3, then:

1. Make sure your bucket name is the same as your domain name
2. Enable static website hosting option in bucket settings.

Answer (score 0):

dhyk57ve7wact.cloudfront.net doesn't resolve. The A record looks fine, assuming you have it configured as an alias.

Comment: I added another screenshot of the A record in edit form. It's my cloudfront distribution domain name

Comment: Right, so it is an alias and the problem is dhyk57ve7wact.cloudfront.net doesn't resolve.